# Get sum qty over specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below table

| substring(area,6,3) | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 |
| 103 | 15 |
| 102 | 11 |
| 104 | 30 |
| 105 | 25 |
| 107 | 17 |
| 108 | 23 |
| 106 | 48 |

And I am looking to get a result as below without repeating the IIF ( as it's a cumulative of 4 sequences) in the area:

| new_area(substring(area,6,3) | sum_qty |
| --- | --- |
| 101-104 | 66 |
| 105-108 | 117 |

I don't know how to create the new area column to be able to get the sum qty

Looking forward to your help.

Please also add an explanation so I will understand how the query is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

We just use the window function row_number() to create the `Grp`

**NOTE:** If you have repeating values in `AREA` use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select new_area = concat(min(area),'-',max(area))
      ,qty = sum(qty)
 From (
        Select area=substring(area,6,3)
              ,qty
              ,Grp = (row_number() over (order by substring(area,6,3))-1) / 4 
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Results**

```
new_area    qty
101-104     66
105-108     113  -- get different results
```

If you were to run the subquery, you would see the following.

[image]

Then it becomes a small matter to aggregate the data grouped by the created column `GRP`

Comment: appriciated the help, i did used it as below and unfortunately am getting an error :

select 
 substring(area,3,2)  
,new_area = concat(min(substring(area,6,3)), '-',max(substring(area,6,3))
,sum(qty) 

from(
select *
,Grp =(row_number() over ( order by area)-1) / 4

from MyTable with (nolock) 

where left(area,2) = '3f'

group by 

left(area,2) 
,substring(area,3,2)  
,Grp

order by substring(area,3,2)
,new_area = concat(min(substring(area,6,3)), '-',max(substring(area,6,3))

Comment: @David Perhaps if you edit your question and provide a better sample (with data types) .   No idea where the substring(area,3,2) is coming from

Comment: my humble apology, cause i thought the substring will not make any difference, i did edit my question also if your kind have a look on how to be fit with  my above query

Comment: @David Had a bad copy .. Updated https://dbfiddle.uk/lrzVC7Ds

Comment: appreciated your kind patience and support 
thx

Comment: @David Hope it truly helped.

Comment: in the Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/rsVb5Wze is working even am changing it but when i try it with live data the min is always = to the max i don't know which syntax is not functioning properly ?is it the row_number or the concat, am using SQL server v18.12.1

Comment: @David you may have repeating values.   change row_number() to dense_rank()